# How can I calculate this integral with dirac delta ?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

$\int_0^{a}ds dv (v s)^{K+n-1}(\frac{d}{d(sv)})^k\delta(2sv-s)$

is it right to obtain

$\int_0^{a}ds dv (v s)^{K+n-1}(\frac{1}{s})^k(\frac{d}{d(v)})^k\frac{1}{2s}\delta(v-1/2)=\int_0^{a}ds  \frac{( s)^{n-2}}{2}(\frac{d}{dv})^k\Bigg[(v)^{k+n-1}\Bigg] _{v=1/2}$

Comment: Is this taken from a reference?

Comment: dear @Qmechanic I've found it in a paper

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: arXiv:1102.5460v2 [hep-ph] 16 Sep 2011 page 15

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.5460